# Passing variable name in custom code in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I need to recognize variable name in SSRS, using Visual Basic. To test it, I created simple function to see how we can pass Object name:

```
Public Function PrintTxt(ByVal Txt As Object) As String
Return Cstr(Txt)
End Function
```

What I find is that I couldn't pass variable name using simple:

```
=Code.PrintTxt(Variables!TotalBudgetSales.Name)
```

but only:

```
=Code.PrintTxt(Variables!TotalBudgetSales.Value)
```

There is any way how I can use variable name in my code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. If you have a variable TotalSalesBudget and its value is set to 12345 then you can get to that value as you have done in your last line of code. If you want the name (TotalSalesBudget) then you can simply type the name `=Code.PrintTxt("TotalSalesBudget")` there is no reason to use the variable object as you have to type its name anyway.

Comment: I use one function in different places, with different arguments and I need to check name of this specific argument.

Comment: So what you mean is you need to get the name of the passed in variable inside your PrintTxt code block? If so then I'm not sure how you can do that other than passing both the value and the name of the variable as separate arguments.

Comment: Yes. PrintTxt is example function created only for this question. How can I pass variable name in your example?

Comment: =Code.PrintTxt(Variables!TotalBudgetSales.Value, "TotalBudgetSales")   If I'm missing the point, please post you current code. You could probably do it with reflection too passing you variable as an object then inspecting the objects name but that's a more complicated approach (and a guess)

Comment: That's the case. I just want to pass one variable and inspect it name.